# Select not NaN values of each row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I would like to get the not NaN values of each row and also to keep it as NaN if that row has only NaNs.

DF =

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | ghi |
| NaN | def | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |
| abc | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |

The result should be like this:

| Result |
| --- |
| ghi |
| def |
| NaN |
| abc |
| NaN |

Comment: `out = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].to_frame('Result')`

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are many different solutions for this. Here is mine

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'a': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'abc', 'NaN'],
        'b': ['NaN', 'def', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
        'c': ['ghi', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ls = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if any(x != "NaN" for x in row.unique()): # checking if there is any element which doesnt match "NaN" in the row
        mismatch = next((x for x in row.unique() if x != "NaN"), None) # if there is a mismatch get that element which mismatch "NaN"
        ls.append(mismatch)
    else:
        ls.append("NaN")

final_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "result":ls
})
```

```
>>> print(final_df)

result
0   ghi
1   def
2   NaN
3   abc
4   NaN
```